# group by day as (48 hour) in a view ms sql server

Tags: sql-server

my table structure as

```
TblID | EmpID |   checkin time | check state
---------------------------------------------
17902   2   2013-06-08 09:43:37.000 1
17951   2   2013-06-09 07:28:58.000 0
17989   2   2013-06-09 15:40:26.000 1
17991   2   2013-06-09 16:28:35.000 0
18008   2   2013-06-09 21:20:13.000 1
18009   2   2013-06-10 11:00:13.000 1
18217   2   2013-06-12 20:11:17.000 0
18247   2   2013-06-13 08:30:19.000 0
18248   2   2013-06-13 08:30:45.000 1
```

all i need to group by the date as 48 hour
and the result will be as

```
Date       | Time 
----------------------------    
2013-06-08  2013-06-08 09:43 
2013-06-08  2013-06-09 07:28
2013-06-08  2013-06-09 15:40 
2013-06-08  2013-06-09 16:28
2013-06-08  2013-06-09 21:20

2013-06-09  2013-06-09 07:28
2013-06-09  2013-06-09 15:40 
2013-06-09  2013-06-09 16:28
2013-06-09  2013-06-09 21:20
2013-06-09  2013-06-10 11:00
```

if my approach is wrong can you suggest another way to calculate attendance when i have employee check-in in a day and check out in the next day.

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query if your SQL Server is 2008 or above:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(M1.[checkin time] AS Date), M2.[checkin time] from MyTable M1
INNER JOIN MyTable M2 
    ON M2.Date BETWEEN CAST(M1.[checkin time] AS Date) AND DATEADD(d, 1, CAST(M1.[checkin time] AS Date))
```

On SQL Server 2005 or below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, M1.[checkin time])), M2.[checkin time] from MyTable M1
INNER JOIN MyTable M2 
    ON M2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, M1.[checkin time])) AND DATEADD(d, 1, DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, M1.[checkin time])))
```

Comment: it works when I changed the 2 days to one day ,thanks